# Discrete space and wronskian

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

Let $I \subset \mathbb R$ be an open interval and $a, b \in C^0(I)$. Consider the following linear differential equation of $2$nd order :
$$\forall t \in I, \quad u''(t) + a(t)u′(t) + b(t)u(t) = 0$$
Let $u_1, u_2$ be two linearly independent solutions of the equation.

Show that the zeros of $u_1$ and $u_2$ are discrete spaces ($\forall x \in I \text{ such that } u_1(x) = 0$, $\exists \alpha>0 \text{ such that }$ $\forall t \in [x-\alpha,x+\alpha]$, $u_1(t)\neq 0,$same for $u_2$). The solution says that since the wronskian of the ODE is not equal to $0$ then there is not $x$ such that $u_1(x)=u_1'(x)=0$ (same for $u_2$). But how does it show that the zeros of $u_1$ and $u_2$ are discrete spaces ?

Answer (score 0):

If $x_0$ is a zero of $u_1$ and you know that $u_1'(x_0)\neq 0$ that means that $u_1$ cuts the $x$-axis transversally. In other words, in a neighborhood of $x_0$ you have $u(x)=A(x-x_0)+B(x)$ where $A\neq 0$ and $B(x)=o(x-x_0)$ as $x\to x_0$. This clearly prevents $u_1$ from having other zeroes in a neighborhood of $x_0$.